# Why does my regex not work in PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I've developed the following regex that I want to use to do a replace in test.txt file data using PowerShell. The regex works fine in the [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) tester but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work from my PowerShell script. It should only select the first ... that includes someAssembly1. However, in PowerShell this is finding the entire file. Anyone have a clue what I'm missing?

Regex:

```
<Reference Include="someAssembly1,[\s\S]*?<\/Reference>
```

[Test.txt]

```
<Reference Include="someAssembly1, Version=12.4.37.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\stage\someAssembly1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="someAssembly2, Version=12.4.37.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\stage\someAssembly2.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="someAssembly3, Version=12.4.37.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\stage\someAssembly3.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

[Powershell Script]

```
$replaceTxt = "<ProjectReference Include=""..\\..\\someAssembly\\someAssembly.csproj"">
<Project>{6ded727e-a756-4c3b-a3fc-c98bd2d61282}</Project>
<Name>someAssembly</Name>
</ProjectReference>"

$findRegex = '<Reference Include="someAssembly1,[\s\S]*?<\/Reference>'

$filePath = "e:/temp/test.txt"

function FindNReplace([string]$filePath, [string]$findTxt, [string]$replaceTxt)
{
    return (Get-Content $filePath -Raw) -replace "$findTxt", "$replaceTxt"  #| Set-Content $filePath
}

FindNReplace -filePath:$filePath -findTxt:$findRegex -replaceTxt:$replaceTxt
```

Comment: `.Replace` replaces literal text. Use `-replace`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tried that. It made no difference.

Comment: You have `return (Get-Content $filePath -Raw).Replace("$findTxt", "$replaceTxt")`, but you need `return (Get-Content $filePath -Raw) -replace $findTxt, $replaceTxt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand and I've updated the above script. However, I still get the same result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry! I'm an idiot. I wasn't looking properly at the returned value. That fixed it. I'd tried something similar in the beginning and it didn't work. I think the addition of the -Raw which I didn't have then was the trick. Thanks!